# Change vtable memory after constructor allocation?

Tags: c++

This was a question asked to me in an interview...

```
Is it possible to change the vtable memory locations after it's 
created via constructor? If yes, is it a good idea? And how to do that? 
If not, why not?
```

As i don't have that in depth idea about C++, my guess is that, it's not possible to change vtable after it's created!

Can anyone explain?

Comment: Simple answers: Yes. Yes. It's automatic. That being answered, what were your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C++ standards do not tell us how dynamic dispatch must be implemented. But vtable is the most common way.

Generally, the first 8 bytes of the object is used to store the pointer to vtable, but only if the object has at least 1 virtual function (otherwise we can save this 8 bytes for something else). And it is not possible to change the records in the vtable during run-time.

But you have memset or memcpy like functions and can do whatever you want (change the vtable pointer).

Code sample:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

class A {
    public:
    virtual void f() {
      std::cout << "A::f()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void g() {
      std::cout << "A::g()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B {
    public:
    virtual void f() {
      std::cout << "B::f()" << std::endl;
    }
    virtual void g() {
      std::cout << "B::g()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    A * p_a = new A();
    B * p_b = new B();
    p_a->f();
    p_a->g();
    p_b->f();
    p_b->g();
    size_t * vptr_a = reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(p_a);
    size_t * vptr_b = reinterpret_cast<size_t *>(p_b);
    std::swap(*vptr_a, *vptr_b);
    p_a->f();
    p_a->g();
    p_b->f();
    p_b->g();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
A::f()
A::g()
B::f()
B::g()
B::f()
B::g()
A::f()
A::g()
```

https://ideone.com/CEkkmN

Of course all these manipulations is the way to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: "first 8 bytes" depends on the size of a pointer, rather, so it could also be 1 byte or 4 bytes. It's also not just that the memory can be saved for something but it must be used to store the first member in order to be compatible to C struct layout.

Comment: @SashaMN I have accepted your answer. Your code example is basically swapping 2 pointers and not changing anything directly in the vtable, right? So the real answer is that, it's not possible to manipulate actual vtable entries?

Comment: If you think that interview question was asking that, I'm afraid you are mistaken, because then, it already made an invalid assumption that the vtable is created in the constructor at all. I believe it was rather about whether the vtable pointer (which is an implementation detail present in many implementations) can change.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt - Based on above example program from SashaMN, the original vtable pointer memory is never changed, right? It's only some local variables get swapped? If my understanding is correct!!

Comment: What exactly is the "vtable pointer memory"? Is it the pointer to the vtable or the vtable itself (which typically consists of pointers, too)?

Comment: @DonK 1 class = 1 vtable.

Objects have only pointers to the vtable of the class.

It's not possible to manipulate vtable entries.

Constructor implicitly initializes the vtable pointer. But you can change this pointer later.

Answer (score 1):

The proper response to that question is simple: This question can't be answered. The question talks about the "vtable memory locations" and then continues with "after it's created via constructor". This sentence doesn't make sense because "locations" is plural while "it" can only refer to a singular.

Now, if *you* have a question concerning the typical C++ implementations that use a vtable pointer, please feel free to ask. I'd also consider reading [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html), which contains a bunch of background infos for people that want to understand how C++ works and why.